# Как можно заменить каждую букву строки на (рандомную) цифру в php

Tags: php

Допустим у нас есть $x = 'Hello world'. У меня появился вопрос, как можно заменить каждую букву в $x на рандомную цифру от 1 до 100?
У меня есть некоторые предположения, которые, почему то, не работают например я пробовал:

```
$x = 'Hello world'; // задаем строку
for($i = 0;$i<strlen($x);$i++){ //цикл, который, по идее, бегает от начала строки до конца строки
    echo str_replace($x[$i], rand(1,100),$x); //вывод замены буквы по индексу на рандомуню цифру с помощью str_replace()
}
```

так же, пробовал с помощью str_split():

```
<?php
$x = 'Hello world';
$arr = str_split($x);
for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++){
    echo str_replace($arr[$i], rand(1,100),$arr);
}
```

но при этом, почему то, появляется много массивов, при выводе которых видно, что буквы в предложении заменены архаично.
Так же, в идеале, хотел бы понять, как можно заменить каждую букву в предложении на ее порядковый номер в алфавите(a = 1, b = 2,c = 3 и т.д) Спасибо

Comment: Алфавит только английский?

Comment: А у меня еще больше вопросов. "*Заменить каждую букву*" - это значит не трогать пробельные символы и знаки препинания? Во-вторых, в вашем примере, в исходной строке есть, например, два символа **o**. Для каждого из этих символов нужно генерировать случайное число или же все **o** должны заменятся одним сгенерированным? Т.е. в первом случае это может быть `Hell77 w88rld`, а во воторм - `Hell77 w77rld`. И в-третьих, регистр символов надо учитывать?

Comment: а почему в задании "заменить", а в коде стоит "вывести"?

Comment: И да, у меня тоже много вопросов. Надо ли будет потом заменять обратно числа на буквы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения "в лоб" (предполагается использование только латиницы):

- Замена каждой буквы на случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до 100:

```php
<?php
$sTxt = 'Hello world';
$sRes = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\w/',  
    function ($matches) {
        return rand(1, 100) . ' '; // Пробел только для примера
    },
    $sTxt
);
echo $sRes;
```

- Замена каждой буквы на её порядковый номер в алфавите:

```php
<?php
$sTxt = 'Hello world';
$sRes = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\w/',  
    function ($matches) {
        return ord(strtoupper($matches[0])) - 64 . ' '; // Пробел только для примера
    },
    $sTxt
);
echo $sRes;
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, этот код работает, но я не могу разобраться с функцией preg_replace_callback(). А именно, какое значение надо вставлять в первый аргумент данной функции(в данном примере, не понятно что такое '/\w/' и за какие критерии строки это отвечает)?

Comment: @yellow_pus: `/\w/` - это [регулярное выражение](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=regexp&page=008). [Почитать](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) про функцию `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, а во втором примере(в рандомное число) не совсем понятно. Зачем и какой элемент находится в [0](где $matches[0]) и зачем мы преобразуем из букв в байты(в верхнем регистре) и отнимаем от этого 64?

Comment: @yellow_pus: рандомное число - это в _первом_ примере ;-) А во втором: 1) Также находим буквы регуляркой, 2) Так как `$matches` возвращает массив, а нам нужен первый (читай, единственный) символ, то `$matches[0]`. 3) Приводим символ к верхнему регистру `strtoupper()`, так как в алфавите, что большие, что маленькие буквы равнозначны. 4) Получаем код текущего символа `ord()` и вычитаем из него смещение (в таблице символов, `A` имеет код 65) - таким образом вычисляем порядковый номер буквы в алфавите.

Comment: Так ord() же возвращает целое число от 0 до 255(https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ord.php)? То есть мы получаем из "H" число, допустим, 210, затем вычитаем 65, получается 146, но это ведь не то число что нам нужно

Comment: @yellow_pus: почему "допустим" то??? Вы путаете `ord()` с `rand()`, скорее всего. `rand()` - генерирует случайное число, а `ord()` - возвращает позицию символа в соответствующей таблице кодировки ( [ASCII](https://snipp.ru/handbk/table-ascii#link-pechatnye-simvoly) в данном случае).

Answer (score 0):

Зацеплюсь за эту часть задачи: "в идеале, хотел бы понять, как можно заменить каждую букву в предложении на ее порядковый номер в алфавите(a = 1, b = 2,c = 3 и т.д) ".

```
$in_glass = "Hello world";
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($in_glass); $i++) {
    $char = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($in_glass, $i, 1));
    $k = 1;
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if ($char == $val) {
            $char = $k;
            break;
        }
        $k++;
    }
    $result .= $char;
}
print $result;
```

> Ответ: 85121215 231518124

Этот же пример с `array_flip()`

```
$in_glass = "Hello world";
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
$array_new = array_flip($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($in_glass); $i++) {
        $char = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($in_glass, $i, 1));
        foreach ($array_new as $val => $value) {
            if ($char == $val) {
                $char = $value+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        $result .= $char;
    }
   print $result;
```

> Ответ:85121215 231518124

На сколько я знаю, нельзя просто пробежать по слову циклом, нужно брать функции, которые вытаскивают букву посимвольно, например [mb_substr](https://php.ru/manual/function.mb-substr.html)
Если расматривать изначальную задачу: "как можно заменить каждую букву в $x на рандомную цифру от 1 до 100?", то вот так:

```
$in_glass = "Hello world";
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($in_glass); $i++) {
        $char = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($in_glass, $i, 1));
        foreach ($array as $val) {
            if ($char == $val) {
                $char = rand(0,100);
                break;
            }
        }
        $result .= $char;
    }
   print $result;
```

> Ответ: 7681812846639 69262692966374

При данном методе не надо учитывать пробелы, знаки препинания и спец символы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129551/discussion-on-answer-by---------).